# The shapes of the array expressions do not conform, Fortran 90

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am trying to achieve the same goal that is gained with the last line of the code, but with a do loop that you can see in my code. The problem is that when I try to form the loop with the command like

```
CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(knot)=(/0.d0/)
```

I get an error

```
The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

```
cdegree=2 
count=5

do knot=0,cdegree+count
if (knot.le.cdegree) then
    CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(knot)=0.d0
    test(knot+1)=0.d0
elseif (knot.ge.count) then
    test(knot+1)=1.d0
    CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(knot)=1.d0   
elseif(nvec.eq.0) then
    num=num+1
    do kn=1,cdegree
       CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(knot+kn-1)=0.5d0  !dble(num)/(dble(count-cdegree-1)/dble(cdegree)+1.d0)
        test(knot+kn)=0.5d0  !dble(num)/(dble(count-cdegree-1)/dble(cdegree)+1.d0)
        nvec=cdegree-1
    enddo
elseif(nvec.ne.0) then 
    nvec=nvec-1
endif
write(14,*)knot,num,nvec,test(knot+1)
enddo    

! CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(0:CURV_KVEC%LENGTH) = (/0.D0,0.D0,0.D0,0.5d0,0.5d0,1.d0,1.d0,1.d0/)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(knot)` is an array element, a scalar. `(/0.d0/)` denotes an array of length 1. These are not the same thing...

Simply writing

```
CURV_KVEC%KNOTS(knot) = 0.d0
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Except the line that is commented out in the code sample has various values, not all of which are zero.  So this solution is not equivalent.

Comment: I finally figured it out! The problem was outside the code that you can see above. The expressions commented in the middle (!dble(num)... and so on) give the value of 0.5. I commented them in order to check if there was a problem there. The values calculated are the components of a knot vector of a NURBS curve so they need to be updated depending on the curve's degree and control points' number. Actually there's no problem in the above code. There is just another loop outside, that causes the above code to be executed twice and some values are not restored before the second loop. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Equating two arrays, the arrays on the left and right hand sides have to have the same shapes.  Here, with 1D arrays that simply means that they have the same lengths.   Since the left-hand side has a run-time determined length of `CURV_KVEC%LENGTH + 1`, you can't use a fixed-length constant array on the right-hand side.

If you want all elements of the array on the LHS to have the same value, then you can use a scaler on the right-hand side, as suggested by @Alexander Vogt, and that value will be broadcast to the array.   I'm interpreting the example code to be that you want different values.  If you want the same values, this is the best solution.

Comment: I finally figured it out! The problem was outside the code that you can see above. The expressions commented in the middle (!dble(num)... and so on) give the value of 0.5. I commented them in order to check if there was a problem there. The values calculated are the components of a knot vector of a NURBS curve so they need to be updated depending on the curve's degree and control points' number. Actually there's no problem in the above code. There is just another loop outside, that causes the above code to be executed twice and some values are not restored before the second loop. Thanks a lot!